# How can I stop nginx from responding to non-local requests?

Tags: nginx

Here's what my nginx file looks like. However when I browse to my server using the ip, I still the the "Welcome to nginx!" page

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:9070;

    root /var/www/[redacted]/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name [redacted];

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is default server that you did not remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you'll find that moving the allow/deny into the `server` clause will clear this up:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:9070;

    root /var/www/[redacted]/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name [redacted];

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
```

becomes:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:9070;

    root /var/www/[redacted]/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name [redacted];

    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks! So now when I try to access my server, the connection isn't immediately killed. It hangs for a few minutes. Any idea why this might be? I'd like to give the illusion that there's nothing at all on that ip.

Comment: Not sure on that one.  A reverse lookup possibly?